# How can I compile iOS ARM assembly code from the command line?

Tags: ios, assembly, compilation, arm

I'm trying to compile an iOS project that contains ARM code using the command line.

Here is the command line:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/as -arch armv6 engines/scumm/smush/codec47ARM.s -o engines/scumm/smush/codec47ARM.o
```

...and here are the errors:

```
engines/scumm/smush/codec47ARM.s:29:Unknown pseudo-op: .global
engines/scumm/smush/codec47ARM.s:29:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 95 (_).
engines/scumm/smush/codec47ARM.s:43:bad instruction `STMFD r13!,{r2,r4-r11,R14}'
engines/scumm/smush/codec47ARM.s:45:bad instruction `LDR r4,[r13,#40]'
engines/scumm/smush/codec47ARM.s:48:bad instruction `SUB r4,r4,#0xF8'
engines/scumm/smush/codec47ARM.s:55:bad instruction `ADD r7,r2,#7'
engines/scumm/smush/codec47ARM.s:56:bad instruction `MOV r7,r7,LSR#3'
```

If I try to compile with gcc (or clang), I receive the following errors:

```
engines/scumm/smush/codec47ARM.s:162:2: error: invalid instruction
 LDREQB r6,[r1],#1 @ r6 = t = *_d_src++
 ^
engines/scumm/smush/codec47ARM.s:279:2: error: invalid instruction
 LDREQB r6,[r1],#1 @ r6 = t = *_d_src++
 ^
engines/scumm/smush/codec47ARM.s:330:2: error: invalid instruction
 LDRLTB r6,[r4,r6] @ r6 = t = _paramPtr[code]
 ^
```

What am I doing wrong?  I believe that ARMv6 should support MOV, ADD, etc.

Comment: Did you specify `-marm` and `-march=armv6` when compiling with gcc?

Comment: Hmmm, -marm is valid but produces a bunch of additional errors.  When I try -march=armv6 it says unknown target CPU.